# Check many variables at once for same value and write conditional - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a bunch of variables that I would like to check `> 0` in js.

Here are my variables (in Angular):

```
        $scope.total_lbs_urea = ($scope.lbs_needed / $scope.urea_n).toFixed(2);
        $scope.total_lbs_ammonium = ($scope.lbs_needed / $scope.ammonium_n).toFixed(2);
        $scope.total_lbs_calcium = ($scope.lbs_needed / $scope.calcium_n).toFixed(2);
        $scope.total_lbs_un32 = ($scope.lbs_needed / $scope.un32_n).toFixed(2);
        $scope.total_lbs_can17 = ($scope.lbs_needed / $scope.can17_n).toFixed(2);
        $scope.total_lbs_aqua = ($scope.lbs_needed / $scope.aqua_n).toFixed(2);

        // weight/gallons variables for gallons of product needed
        $scope.total_gal_urea = ($scope.total_lbs_urea / $scope.urea_g).toFixed(2);
        $scope.total_gal_ammonium = ($scope.total_lbs_ammonium / $scope.ammonium_g).toFixed(2);
        $scope.total_gal_calcium = ($scope.total_lbs_calcium / $scope.calcium_g).toFixed(2);
        $scope.total_gal_un32 = ($scope.total_lbs_un32 / $scope.un32_g).toFixed(2);
        $scope.total_gal_can17 = ($scope.total_lbs_can17 / $scope.can17_g).toFixed(2);
        $scope.total_gal_aqua = ($scope.total_lbs_aqua / $scope.aqua_g).toFixed(2);

        // phosophorus variables to get phosphorus needed
        $scope.total_p_urea = ($scope.lbs_needed * $scope.urea_p).toFixed(2);
        $scope.total_p_ammonium = ($scope.lbs_needed * $scope.ammonium_p).toFixed(2);
        $scope.total_p_calcium = ($scope.lbs_needed * $scope.calcium_p).toFixed(2);
        $scope.total_p_un32 = ($scope.lbs_needed * $scope.un32_p).toFixed(2);
        $scope.total_p_can17 = ($scope.lbs_needed * $scope.can17_p).toFixed(2);
        $scope.total_p_aqua = ($scope.lbs_needed * $scope.aqua_p).toFixed(2);            

        // potassium(k) variables to get potassium(k) needed
        $scope.total_k_urea = ($scope.lbs_needed * $scope.urea_k).toFixed(2);
        $scope.total_k_ammonium = ($scope.lbs_needed * $scope.ammonium_k).toFixed(2);
        $scope.total_k_calcium = ($scope.lbs_needed * $scope.calcium_k).toFixed(2);
        $scope.total_k_un32 = ($scope.lbs_needed * $scope.un32_k).toFixed(2);
        $scope.total_k_can17 = ($scope.lbs_needed * $scope.can17_k).toFixed(2);
        $scope.total_k_aqua = ($scope.lbs_needed * $scope.aqua_k).toFixed(2); 

        // sulfur variables to get potassium(k) needed
        $scope.total_s_urea = ($scope.lbs_needed * $scope.urea_s).toFixed(2);
        $scope.total_s_ammonium = ($scope.lbs_needed * $scope.ammonium_s).toFixed(2);
        $scope.total_s_calcium = ($scope.lbs_needed * $scope.calcium_s).toFixed(2);
        $scope.total_s_un32 = ($scope.lbs_needed * $scope.un32_s).toFixed(2);
        $scope.total_s_can17 = ($scope.lbs_needed * $scope.can17_s).toFixed(2);
        $scope.total_s_aqua = ($scope.lbs_needed * $scope.aqua_s).toFixed(2); 

        // calcium variables to get potassium(k) needed
        $scope.total_c_urea = ($scope.lbs_needed * $scope.urea_c).toFixed(2);
        $scope.total_c_ammonium = ($scope.lbs_needed * $scope.ammonium_c).toFixed(2);
        $scope.total_c_calcium = ($scope.lbs_needed * $scope.calcium_c).toFixed(2);
        $scope.total_c_un32 = ($scope.lbs_needed * $scope.un32_c).toFixed(2);
        $scope.total_c_can17 = ($scope.lbs_needed * $scope.can17_c).toFixed(2);
        $scope.total_c_aqua = ($scope.lbs_needed * $scope.aqua_c).toFixed(2);
```

I want to do something like this:

```
        if ($scope.[VARIABLE FOR EACH HERE] > 0) {
            $scope.isActive = true;
        } else {
            $scope.isActive = false;
        }
```

Any idea how to do this?

SOLUTION:

Ended up just using jQuery...

```
        $( "tr" ).each(function() {
            var number = parseInt($(this).find('td').text(), 10);
            if (number > 0) {
                $(this).find('td').addClass("table-background");
            } else {
                $(this).find('td').removeClass("table-background");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I would save all those variables inside an object into the scope like so:

```
$scope.variables = {
    total_lbs_urea: ($scope.lbs_needed / $scope.urea_n).toFixed(2),
    $scope.total_lbs_ammonium: ($scope.lbs_needed /$scope.ammonium_n).toFixed(2),
    $scope.total_lbs_calcium: ($scope.lbs_needed / $scope.calcium_n).toFixed(2)
    ...etc
};
```

And then loop through them like so:

```
$scope.isActive = false; //start with false
for(var prop in $scope.variables){
   if($scope.variables.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
       if($scope.variables[prop] > 0){
            $scope.isActive = true;
            break;  //add this if you want to stop looping at the first variable that is > 0 
       }
   }
}
//if nothing is > 0, $scope.isActive will have remained false at this point
```

Comment: ran into some errors used some jquery instead seems to work fine. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I fully understand your question, but you might be able to use an array of item names and iterate using the `.some()` method.

```
['item1', 'item2', 'item3'].some(function(item) {
  $scope.isActive = ($scope[item] > 0);
  return $scope.isActive;
});
```